# Keycloak Client doesn't have secret available with Access Type Public

Tags: spring, rest, keycloak

I am using Keycloak 3.4.3 and protecting Spring based Rest service.

Below is Keycloak client configuration:

```
Client Protocol: openid-connect<br>
Access Type: public<br>
Standard Flow Enabled: ON<br>
Implicit Flow<br>
Direct Access Grants Enabled: ON<br>
Authorization Enabled: OFF<br>
```

Is it important to provide secret with Access Type as public. If yes, how can I provide secret as I couldn't find any option in the Keycloak client configuration. Please help.

> 2018-02-28 15:19:10.216  WARN 7813 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   a.a.ClientIdAndSecretCredentialsProvider : Client 'democlientid'
>   doesn't have secret available 2018-02-28 15:19:10.375 ERROR 7813 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : failed to
>   turn code into token
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>           at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
>           at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>   ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest.invokeAccessCodeToToken(ServerRequest.java:111)
>   ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:336)
>   ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:281)
>   ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:139)
>   ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticateInternal(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:203)
>   ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:50)
>   [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.doAuthenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:57)
>   [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:586)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
>           at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181)
>   ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds this question - the answer seems to be that public access types are for browser logins using Keycloak's UI only.  Eg you can't use a Spring UI with the Keycloak plugin - they must use the Confidential access type (in which case you get a "Credentials" tab in the Clients section of the admin UI giving the secret).

See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_admin/#oidc-clients and scroll down to "Access Type"

Answer (score -1):

If you will check the client `admin-cli` under the `master` realm ,you will easily able to understand why the by default mentioned `access-type=public`  for this client.
FYI just check the below details from official documents

**Access Type**

This defines the type of the OIDC client.

1. Confidential access type is for server-side clients that need to perform a browser login and require a client secret when they turn an access code into an access token, (see Access Token Request in the OAuth 2.0 spec for more details). This type should be used for server-side applications.
   public
2. Public access type is for client-side clients that need to perform a browser login. With a client-side application there is no way to keep a secret safe. Instead it is very important to restrict access by configuring correct redirect URIs for the client.
3. Bearer-only access type means that the application only allows bearer token requests. If this is turned on, this application cannot participate in browser logins.

So your client have Public access type so it mean you want to do login for client-site application so for public access-type keyclock wont give secret key.

Apart from your question,another advantage of this,user can use keyclock from command prompt as well. You can login like this

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server https://<IP ADDRESS>:8666/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin --client admin-cli
```

you can perform admin task like

1. Creating a new realm.
2. Creating clients under new realm
3. Creating users/group etc.

Comment: I know it is little old thread, but I have a question here. I want to enable authorization in keycloak which requires keycloak client to be set as confidential. How my webapp clients will work here in this case (as secret is not available to them)? Webapp client get session id from server after authentication (where keycloak is running using oidc login) but it does not work with other rest calls having different uri.

Answer (score -2):

You have a configuration error; the server address is not right.